# Using both GSuite and third party email hosting

Tags: email, email-server, gmail, g-suite

Is it possible to use 1 domain that running simultaneously with 2 email hosting / services? I mean  in my company, a management level will using g suite. On other hands, a staff level just using email services like horde or roundcube. How to do that?

Comment: Internet mail is routed based on the MX record(s) set for the (sub) domain.  
At the DNS level there is simply not sufficient granularity possible to provide a way to instruct a sender that messages for `alice@example.com` need to be routed differently from messages addressed to `bob@example.com` which should end up with a different provider.

You need to uses different (sub-) domains.

Comment: @HBruijn did you mean if we add sub domain eg. sub.example.com we can routing to web mail and example.com to gsuite?

Comment: Yes  and that means that you would end up with `alice@example.com` and `bob@web.example.com` and two sets of MX records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible since we setup the MX records for mail protocal(SMTP). Either we need to use G Suite or Webmail, both not possible at a time for single domain.